# How can i get from a FileInfo[] the file full name full directory including the file extension?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is the code:

```
FileInfo[] flist = d.GetFiles();
if (flist.GetLength(0) > 0)
{
    foreach (FileInfo txf in flist)
    {
        string fn = txf.FullName + txf.Extension;
    }
}
```

If i'm doing only fullname it will give me the directory+file name but without the Extension.
And if i'm doing it: string fn = txf.FullName + txf.Extension; Extension is empty ""

I need to get it full like this for exmaple: c:\test.png
Or that fn will contain: c:\temp\dir\testing.jpg

Full directory path + full file name + the file name extension

Comment: See [System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods.

Comment: When I do this - `var fi = new FileInfo(@"X:\Folder\Subfolder\file.ext"); Console.WriteLine(fi.FullName);` - I get the full path including the extension.

Comment: And you don't need here neither `GetLength(0) > 0` nor `Length > 0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `FullName` field of a `FileInfo` object includes full path, file name and file extension (`FileInfo` inherits `FullName` from `FileSystemInfo`). So it is more like the code, which is in charge for creating these files, is not appending the proper extension (Assuming `d` is a `DirectoryInfo` and not other - maybe homemade - class).